# Find substitution of a decimal number from s-box

Tags: s-boxes

```
    |  00   01   10   11
 ---|-------------------------------
 00 | 0011 0100 1111 0001
 01 | 1010 0110 0101 1011
 10 | 1110 1101 0100 0010
 11 | 0111 0000 1001 1100
```

I need to find out a substitution of 2. I dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified the input encoding.

If the row index bits are the more significant bits, the input $(row,col)=(00,10)$ corresponds to 2 which leads to the output $0100$ which is 4 in decimal.

If the column index bits are the more significant bits, the input $(row,col)=(10,00)$ corresponds to the output $1110$ which is 12 in decimal.

Comment: $(00,10)$ corresponds to 0100 or 1111